# Maven dependency for aqapi13.jar

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jms, activemq-classic

I am upgrading a project from Ant to Gradle. The project uses a aqapi13.jar(this is oracle aq jar. This is needed as the project reads from an oracle-queue and writes to an activemq queue.)

The ant project contains the jar aqapi13.jar in the libs folder. But iam trying to get this dependency from a repository instead of having it in the libs folder.

However, iam not able to find a repository which contains this jar. All the repositories that I have seen contain aqapi13-9i.jar, but not aqapi13.jar.

Anyone knows the difference between aqapi13.jar and aqapi13-9i.jar and how to get the needed aqapi13.jar from a repository.

Advance Thanks

Comment: `aqapi13-9i.jar` is for Oracle 9i. I guess `aqapi13.jar` is for Oracle 11g and it is Licensed under Oracle DB licenses and that is the reason why you couldn't find it in a public repo. This is one of the issues with Maven that I hate. You may want to use Artifactory Maven Repo Manager to create your own Repository, it is much safer that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some dependencies are never found in public repositories because of the license they have.

One way to use this dependencies is to create your own repository (e.g. artifactory, nexus, archiva). Then you are free to put in every artifact you want (as long as you do not publish the repository). This repository can also serve as a mirror for maven.

Another way could be to mark this dependency as [system scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).